# R markdown beamer presentation returning undefined control sequence

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer

Whenever I tried to knit R markdown in beamer presentation format, it keeps on giving me undefined control sequence.

It is fraustrating because it worked fine until yesterday and I have no idea what I changed that causes this error.
To show that my code is not the source of the problem, I simply tried to knit an empty page.

*code:*

```
---
title: "untitled"
output: beamer_presentation
---
```

*Output:*

```
output file: a.knit.md

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...{subsubsection}\addtobeamertemplate 
                                                  {theorem begin}{\expandaft...
l.322 }{}
```

My original file returns the exaclty same error message.

I tried:

1. reinstall LaTeX
2. reinstall RStudio
3. upgrade all packages in R

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is this your complete code?

Comment: Yes. That's my complete code and yet it returns error. I want to know what is the source of the problem.

Comment: This problem was just fixed in beamer. @JosephWright is building a new release of beamer as we speak. It should be available from ctan tomorrow

Comment: if a package update (in this case hyperref) cause such a problem it seldom helps to reinstall everything. As a reinstall also removes your backups it actually makes it more difficult to revert the update.  The problem should be resolved tomorrow. A work-around has been posted here https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/236#issuecomment-1128510029.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was just [fixed by @UlrikeFischer](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/20638065ff0be3a0cdaac23185172bfe1e38b2b8). @JosephWright is preparing a new beamer release as we speak, it should be available as beamer v3.67 on ctan tomorrow.

As a temporary workaround, place these two files in the folder of your .rmd file:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/main/base/beamer.cls
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/main/base/beamerbasesection.sty

(don't forget to delete these files again once you have the new beamer version, otherwise they might interfere with future updates)